# Using same selenium webdriver object after a test suite has aborted

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Can we continue with the same webdriver after a test execution has abruptly stopped.

I am currently using a webdriver reference in all test cases but need to reuse the same driver object afer i restart a test suite again.

After searching i got that we can get the driver's session id
Can we use the session id to reinitialize the driver

Also searched that it can be done with remote webdriver. But dont know How exactly it will work.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can certainly use the session id of the webdriver but for this you have to store the session id at the time of initializing  in order to use it later. 
for details see this blog post

For chrome browser 
http://binaryclips.com/2015/08/25/selenium-webdriver-in-c-how-to-use-the-existing-window-of-chrome-browser/

For firefox browser
http://binaryclips.com/2014/09/16/selenium-web-driver-in-c-how-to-continue-script-on-the-already-opened-browser-instance/